# ajax request to api is successful, but error event fires instead

Tags: json, ajax, http, https

I deployed my API on Heroku, which contains a database. Connected it to pgAdmin to monitor my db.

Now when I do some AJAX requests, the results show up in the database. But the error event in my ajax request fires instead of the success event.

*note: I saw a SO answer where I remove my `dataType: "json"` line in my AJAX, but still it's the same error. I also confirmed the response of my API, and it is valid JSON. Here's my request:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "https://pva-api.herokuapp.com/api/login",
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: JSON.stringify({
         'username': username,
         'password': password
     }),
     type: "GET",
     crossDomain: true,
     headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
     },
     success: function (resp) {
         alert('success');
     },
     error: function (err) {
         console.error(err);
     },
     complete: function (jqXHR) {
         if (jqXHR.status == '401') {
             console.log(jqXHR.status)
         }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
.done( function(){ ....)

.fail( function(){ ....)
```

this is the preferred way of going about ajax requests now since the implementation of $.Deferreds.

See how you go with that.

Comment: so is it of the form $.ajax({..request here...}).done(function () {...}).fail(function (){....}) ?

Comment: tried what you suggested, and it goes to the error function

Comment: remove the error function maybe, it should not be going there unless there is an error

Comment: the error is very weird indeed. It worked normally for like a few hours, then after that it went back to displaying that error. I dunno why